# Get reference to cell containing function

Tags: excel-dna

Is there is way to access cell that contains my UDF?
I need to reset some cache when function with same parameters is run from different cell.
Didn't find anything suitable in exceldna utils.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call

```
ExcelReference caller = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfCaller) as ExcelReference;
```

The result will be an `ExcelReference` if you're called from a sheet formula. It might be `null` if you're called via `Application.Run` or a few other ways.

`ExcelReference` is a wrapper for the C API sheet reference.

Comment: Thanks Govert. I'm using sheet formulas

Comment: By calling `XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfCaller)` I always get `ExcelErrorRef {23}` - why?